# Get GUID by term name - jsom

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I need to pass term name as a parameter and return the GUID of that particular term.

As an example if I pass My Term 1 it should return GUID of My Term 1.

[image]

```
var termGuid=getTermByName('My Term 1');

function getTermByName(TermName){

    return term.get_id();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[SP.Taxonomy.TermStore.getTerms Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269620.aspx) could be utilized for finding [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) in [TermStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269589.aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to find a [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) by Label using JSOM:

```
function findTermsByLabel(label,success,error)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var ts = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
     var matchInfo = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(ctx);
     matchInfo.set_termLabel(label);
     matchInfo.set_trimUnavailable(true);
     var termMatches = ts.getTerms(matchInfo);
     ctx.load(termMatches);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
           var terms = termMatches.get_data();
           success(terms);
        },
        error);    
}
```

Usage

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession'], function(){

   var termLabel = '--term label goes here--';

   findTermsByLabel(termLabel,
     function(terms){
        if(terms.length == 0)
            console.log('Term has not been found');
        else if(terms.length > 1)    
            console.log(String.format("Several Terms exist with '{0}' label",termLabel));
        else {
            console.log(String.format('Term has been found: {0}'),terms[0].get_id().toString());     
        }    
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     });

});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it always gives 'Term has not been found' .. not sure the reason yet.. (I've given existing term name correctly)

Comment: Ya, i will definitely vote up, because its very difficult to find share-point JSOM resources. All of your previous answer were very very helpful, I'm trying to find out the issue. It always says Term has not been found, but i've given an existing label name

Comment: Hm.. since the specified example works for me, are you sure that provided term label really exist?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint-Online 2013, is there any mismatch with sharepoint-online and this code ?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I tried the above code. not working for me. not sure whats wrong. Term name I am providing do exists. Env SP Online